# tensorflow 2.4.1 requires six~=1.15.0, but you have six 1.16.0 which is incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, compiler-errors, pytorch, runtime-error

Iam getting this error:-

```
    [31mERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
104 1m 15s  tensorflow 2.4.1 requires six~=1.15.0, but you have six 1.16.0 which is incompatible.[
```

when i try to import packages torch and datasets for huggingface summarization in my client's environment.

```
pandas
numpy
torch
datasets==1.14.0
transformers==4.11.3
rouge-score==0.0.4
nltk==3.6.5
pyarrow==6.0.0

beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
numpy
pandas
lxml
requests==2.23.0
wikipedia==1.4.0
```

These are the packages that I am giving as requirements. Could it be that one of these is installing six=1.16 and uninstalling six=1.15?

Here is the further detail of the log

```
Downloading cnvrg-0.7.51-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
24  5m 22s  [?25l
25  5m 22s  [?25hRequirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.15.0)
26  5m 22s  Collecting six
27  5m 22s  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
[?25l

Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.11.0->google-cloud-storage->cnvrg) (0.4.8)
83  5m 22s  Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pyaml->cnvrg) (5.4.1)
84  5m 22s  Installing collected packages: six, urllib3, requests, azure-core, azure-storage-blob, cnvrg
85  5m 22s  Attempting uninstall: six
86  5m 22s  Found existing installation: six 1.15.0
87  5m 22s  Uninstalling six-1.15.0:
88  5m 22s  Successfully uninstalled six-1.15.0
```

Eventually, this error is not allowing me to import both torch and datasets.

Can anyone help in resolving this

Answer (score 1):

after installing all dependencies, install `six 1.15.0`

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then run

```
pip install six~=1.15.0
```

or

```
pip install six==1.15.0
```

Comment: the environment is using requirements.txt file to install the packages, pip doesn't work there

Comment: are you using conda? if yes you can still use pip.